# Derivation of Noether's theorem by Gateaux derivative

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations, symmetric-groups, gateaux-derivative

Noether's theorem states that if:

$\ \int_{a}^{b} F(x, y, y') \,dx  = \ \int_{a_{new}}^{b_{new}} F(x_{new}, y_{new}, y_{new}') \,dx_{new} $

for any $a$, $b$ and $y(x)$, and when $x$ and $x_{new}$ and $y$ and $y_{new}$ are of transformations:

$x_{new} = \Phi(x, y, y', \epsilon)$

$y_{new} = \Psi(x, y, y', \epsilon)$

$x = \Phi(x, y, y', \epsilon = 0)$

$y = \Psi(x, y, y', \epsilon = 0)$

$\epsilon$ is a variable scalar parameter, and if $y^*(x)$ is an extremal of the functional $\ \int_{a}^{b} F(x, y, y') \,dx$, meaning that $y^*(x)$ satisfies:

$\frac{\partial F(x, y^*, y^{*'})}{\partial y^*} = \frac{d}{dx} \frac{\partial F(x, y^*, y^{*'})}{\partial y^{*'}}$

then there is

$\frac{\partial F(x, y^*, y^{*'})}{\partial y^{*'}} \psi(x, y^*, y^{*'}) + (F(x, y^*, y^{*'}) - y^{*'}\frac{\partial F(x, y^*, y^{*'})}{\partial y^{*'}})\phi(x, y^*, y^{*'}) = \text{constant}$, with

$\phi(x, y, y') = \frac{\partial \Phi(x, y, y', \epsilon)}{\partial \epsilon}\vert{_{\epsilon = 0}}$

$\psi(x, y, y') = \frac{\partial \Psi(x, y, y', \epsilon)}{\partial \epsilon}\vert{_{\epsilon = 0}}$

My question is: is it possible to derive

$\frac{\partial F(x, y^*, y^{*'})}{\partial y^{*'}} \psi(x, y^*, y^{*'}) + (F(x, y^*, y^{*'}) - y^{*'}\frac{\partial F(x, y^*, y^{*'})}{\partial y^{*'}})\phi(x, y^*, y^{*'}) = \text{constant}$

from

$\frac{d{\ \int_{a_{new}}^{b_{new}} F(x_{new}, y_{new}, y_{new}') \,dx_{new} }}{d\epsilon}\vert{_{\epsilon = 0}}$ ?

I read some proof for example, https://drchristianphsalas.com/2020/08/06/proving-noethers-theorem/, but I don't understand the procedures such as ignoring the high order terms, so that only the linear part is used, bla bla.... I want to know if it is possible to only use total derivatives and/or partial derivatives to derive the equations. If so, could you demonstrate that derivation? Thank you all.

Comment: "Ignoring the higher order terms so that the linear part is used" is, essentially, a way of saying that you are taking the Gateaux derivative. So, that's the proof you need, even though you need to translate it to your language, unfortunately. That's one of the most annoying tasks of mathematics, if you ask me, but that's life.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That's where I struggle. My background is engineering, my math is poor. The only way I feel comfortable is to write down explicitly the Gateaux derivative, manipulate terms using integration by parts bla bla. But I find it is very difficult in the derivation of Nother's theorem by doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me expand on my comment. Consider a function $f\colon \mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$, for simplicity. The Gateaux derivative reduces to the directional derivative, that is
$$
D_vf(x)=\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial \epsilon}f(x+\epsilon v)\right|_{\epsilon=0}. $$
This can be obtained by Taylor expansion, as hinted by the note you are citing; indeed,
$$
f(x+\epsilon v)=f(x)+D_v f(x) \epsilon + o(\epsilon), $$
so to compute $D_v f(x)$ you have to "ignore the higher order terms" (that is, ignore that $o(\epsilon)$) and "use only the linear part" (that is, use only the coefficient of $\epsilon$). The quotation marks refer to the words from the notes that you mentioned.

**Example**. Consider the functional
$$ 
\Phi(y)=\int_a^b y(x)^4\, dx.$$
This is a function of $y$, which itself is a function of $x$. This is why we call $\Phi$ a "functional".

We want to compute the following directional derivative, or Gateaux derivative;
$$
D_y \Phi(y^\star)=\left.\frac{\partial }{\partial \epsilon}\Phi(y^\star +\epsilon y)\right|_{\epsilon=0}.$$
To do so we want to use the method just introduced. So, we compute the Taylor expansion via the binomial theorem;
$$
\Phi(y^\star +\epsilon y)=\int_a^b(y^\star(x))^4\, dx +4\epsilon \int_a^b (y^\star(x))^3y(x)\, dx+ o(\epsilon).$$
Note that we did not write the terms in $\epsilon^2, \epsilon^3, \epsilon^4$, since we are not going to need them. Instead, we sweeped all those terms under the $o(\epsilon)$. (We could have used $O(\epsilon^2)$ instead of $o(\epsilon)$. It would have been the same). And now we are ready to read our result;
$$
D_y \Phi(y^\star)=4 \int_a^b (y^\star(x))^3y(x)\, dx.$$

Comment: Thanks, I understand you point. If I want to do the Gateaux stuff, I guess the first step is to write:  $\frac{d{\ \int_{a_{new}}^{b_{new}} F(\Phi(x, y, y', \epsilon), \Psi(x, y, y', \epsilon), d(\Psi(x, y, y', \epsilon))/dx) \,d(\Phi(x, y, y', \epsilon)) }}{d\epsilon}\vert{_{\epsilon = 0}}$. That's a mess for me, I don't know what should be the next step...

Comment: This is too messy. For starters, assume that $a=a_{\text{new}}=-\infty, b=b_{\text{new}}=\infty$ and that every function only depends on $y$ and $y'$. This already contains all important ideas.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know what to do with that mess. I feel that following strict derivation it should eventually lead to the Noether's result. But I don't know the procedures. Especially $d(\Phi(x, y, y', \epsilon))$, I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: You are right, that's simply differentiating the integral and noting that such differential must vanish, because of the assumption of invariance. Nothing more than that, no higher mathematics. The computations are annoying, however. I don't think I'll have time to review them right now

Comment: Thank you very much. Appreciate all your help.

Comment: When you say 'to compute $D_vf(x)$ you have to ''ignore the higher order terms"', what do you mean by 'have to'? Since $D_vf(x)\epsilon = f(x+\epsilon v) - f(x) - o(\epsilon)$ is exact, and $D_vf(x)\epsilon$ is only the linear part of $ f(x+\epsilon v) - f(x)$, why your argument is legitimate to get rid of $o(\epsilon)$ in the derivation?

Comment: I understand from the numerical aspect that ignoring $o(\epsilon)$ wouldn't hurt. But in any exact derivation, like the one to derive the Noether's theorem, why does ignoring $o(\epsilon)$ do not cause any problem in an exact way?

Comment: Formally you are dividing by $\epsilon$ and taking the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$. In practice doing so would make things even messier than they already are. So you just take the coefficient of $\epsilon$ and disregard the ones of $\epsilon^2, \epsilon^3$ etc...

Comment: Please correct me if I understand wrongly. For the Geteaux derivative, essentially we are calculating a limit by making $\epsilon$ arbitrarily close to $0$. For all those higher order terms such as $\epsilon^2$, $\epsilon^3$, they are exactly $0$, so they can be dropped out in the derivation. So dropping out those high order terms in the derivation is not approximation but still exact (or precise, analytical, you know what I mean). ?